# "Target Machine Actively Refused" from Deadline10

Tags: localhost, syntax-error, port, firewall

I'm new to the community and very new to MongoDB. Knowledge of coding is limited to C++ and HTML.

We're setting up *MongoDB* for *Deadline10*, to farm out render jobs. DB will sit on the same machine as Deadline render manager (Repository), thus shouldn't need external connections. Deadline 10 handles connections to external render units.

I've been at it for a week, but am stuck. When connecting to MongoDB with Deadline, I get

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.1.150.27:27017"

- Connections to port 27017 are allowed on Windows firewall
- No sign that Symantec is blocking it, either
- MongoDB is initialized, as far as I can tell

Only concern is in the Mongod.exe command window. System bound to local host, "Remote Systems will be unable to connect to this server." However, Deadline 10 exists on the same machine. So do I need to enable a *remote IP*?

Trying to use the `--bind_ip` command to bind to the system's own IP (in the Mongoshell) gives me a syntax error. I tried `--bind_ip <10.1.150.27>`

Not sure where to go from here and I'm open to suggestions/questions!